# How can I obtain a responsive design in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk, responsive

my question is, How can I built a responsive application in corona sdk, which adapted to any platform. I will appreciate any advice that you give me, thanks.

Comment: I have built several for Android and iOS, it is fairly fast on them. What other platform do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding using a smart config.lua file to cover off device and images.
https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/10/modernizing-the-config-lua/

Caching display variables and referencing a percentage of them
e.g. top/left/bottom/right etc.

Here is some sample code that will give you an idea.

```
local screenTop
local screenBottom
local screenLeft
local screenRight

-- Get current edges of visible screen
screenTop = display.screenOriginY
screenBottom = display.viewableContentHeight + display.screenOriginY
screenLeft = display.screenOriginX
screenRight = display.viewableContentWidth + display.screenOriginX

--show some text using a percentage of above (centered and 1/3 down)
local myText = display.newText("Hello World", (0.50 * screenRight), (0.33 * screenBottom), native.systemFont, 36)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot.